# JsonMediaTypeFormatter mock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I have no idea if anyone can help me but I'll ask all the same.

I am trying to Mock/Stub JsonMediaTypeFormatter in my unit test and I seem to be having trouble setting up the stub properties. I would like to be able to set the mock with this setting

```
SerializerSettings = { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
```

Like such

```
_mockFormatter.SetUp(f => f.SerializerSettings = { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
```

However, this is not a possibility in Moq. Does anyone know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not at a .net compiler so I can't test/tweak it but if this doesn't work, it should get you headed in the right direction.

```
_mockFormatter.SetUp(
    f => f.SerializerSettings = () => 
    { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }
);
```

You have to account for you are passing a function into the setup, even though the function is just setting up an anonymous object with one property. The `() =>` lambda should take care of that for you.